# Passing Global Variables

Tags: variables, parameter-passing, shopify

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass Shopify Global Variable, such as {{ discount_code }} for example, as a Custom Variable/Dimension into the "Additional Scripts" textarea.

We really just want to know if we can get the discount_code parameter in the thankyou page by giving the proper variable syntax.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://docs.shopify.com/support/settings/checkout-and-payment/how-do-i-customize-my-thank-you-page) on the Shopify wiki on how to customise your thank you page.

It says:

> In the Additional Content & Scripts box, you can use:
>
> - HTML — anything goes here, you can use script, style, iframe and object elements, any valid HTML5 element is fair game.
> - **Liquid — you're somewhat limited to what Liquid you can use, but you have access to the essentials, that is, the order and the shop variables.**

So, you should be able to access the `discounts` property from the [order variable](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/order).